# Simple database Connection error in C#

Tags: c#

I'm receiving the following error message:

```
invalidOperationException was unhandled
```

In the following code:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DASTGIRKHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBProject;Integrated    Security=True;Pooling=False");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO EmployeeRecord Values(" + tfCode.Text   + ",'" + tfName.Text + "','" + tfCell.Text + "','" + tfAdrs + "',)");
    cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully");
}
```

Comment: There should be only a single gap like in `Integrated Security`.

Comment: `SqlCommand` is not associated with a connection. You need to set `conn` to the command.

Comment: There is also an extra comma at the end of the Insert just before the last parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidOperationException` exception is thrown when you invoke `BeginExecuteNonQuery` method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ca56w9se%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and you not specified "Asynchronous Processing=true" in the connection string.

You should also set connection to your command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO EmployeeRecord Values(" + tfCode.Text   + ",'" + tfName.Text + "','" + tfCell.Text + "','" + tfAdrs + "')", conn);
```

**InvalidOperationException**

> The name/value pair "Asynchronous Processing=true" was not included
>   within the connection string defining the connection for this
>   SqlCommand. The SqlConnection closed or dropped during a streaming
>   operation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but your code has many errors. Let me show a different approach

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cnString = @"Data Source=DASTGIRKHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;
                        Initial Catalog=DBProject;
                        Integrated Security=True;";
    string cmdText = @"Insert INTO EmployeeRecord 
                       Values(@code,@fname,@cell,@adr)";
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
         conn.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", Convert.ToInt32(tfCode.Text));
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", tfName.Text );
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", tfCell.Text  );
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adr", tfAdrs.Text);
         int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if(rowInserted > 0) 
              MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully");
         else
              MessageBox.Show("Insert failes");
    }
}
```

The primary cause of your error is stated by the answer of [kmatyaszek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410998/kmatyaszek), but this is just the tip of the iceberg.

You should always use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around your disposable objects like the connection. This will ensure that the connection is closed and disposed also in case of exceptions.

You should use a parameterized query to create your command to avoid [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and parsing problems. For example, a single quote in the `tfName` textbox could lead to a Syntax Error.

The call to `BeginExecuteNonQuery`, excludes the call to `ExecuteNonQuery` and requires a call to  `EndExecuteNonQuery`.

Finally, the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` tells you if the insertion is successful.

As a last note, I have remove the `Pooling=False` from the connection string.
You haven't said anything why do you want avoid his very useful optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I'd print that SQL text.  Looks like there's an unbalanced apostrophe to me.

Better yet, use a .NET class that binds parameters for you.  Easier and better SQL injection projection, too.

Answer (score 0):

What are **tfCode, tfName,tfCell,tfAdrs**? I assume they are textbox control?
if so you are using **tfAdrs** instead of **tfAdrs.Text**

also assign connection string to the command and remove additional space in
"Integrated security"

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate yourself, use `Parameterized Insert` instead of concatenation, which its prone to SQL Injection.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmployeeRecord VALUES(@tfCode, @tfName, @tfCell, @tfAdrs)", conn);

command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tfCode", trCode);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tfName", tfName);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tfCell", tfCell);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tfAdrs", tfAdrs);
```

Comment: @DastgirKhan Your welcome, please make sure to accept an answer.